# installing R2jags library in HPC linux

Tags: r, linux

I am trying to install R2jags an r package in HPC linux environment, but doesn't work. This does work in windows, but not in HPC linux. I tried several options like:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/R2jags_0.5-7.tar.gz", repos=NULL
```

but ends up with error:

ERROR: dependency 'rjags' is not available for package 'R2jags'
* removing '/ddn/home/grpl22/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/R2jags'
Warning message:
In install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/R2jags_0.5-7.tar.gz",  :
installation of package '/tmp/Rtmprf6lN0/downloaded_packages/R2jags_0.5-7.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status

any sugeestion please how i can install this?

Comment: The `repos=NULL` argument is for _local_ files yet you are trying to access a `https://` remote URL.  Did you try to (standard, normal, documented) approach of `install.packages("R2jags")` ? The package is there so need for anything special: https://cran.r-project.org/package=R2jags

Comment: with standard install.packages('R2jags') -        doesn't work

Comment: With an HPC, likely can't install from online repos, so you'll need to manually ensure all dependencies (like `rjags`) are met. In my experience, the best thing to do would be to talk to the administrator. They can likely get this worked out for you much easier and faster than you ever could yourself. Of course, that's just my experience (my admin is super nice and honestly would prefer to manage these things himself), YMMV...